# Recommendations for a simple search engine for bag of words?

Tags: search, full-text-search, tags, tagging

Any recommendations for small, lightweight, bag of words search engine?

I have a set of 'documents' that are each basically a small bag of arbitrary words.
Given a new document, I need to get a list of 'similar' documents along with some weight for how similar they might be.  Documents are likely to be small.. a couple paragraphs at most.

- Stemming would be great but not highly required.
- Word expansion with word nets not required.
- opensource or freeware preferred, as this is a prototype, not a full-blow project.
- unix/linux platform preferred.

I'd be using it as a subcomponent and expect only to feed it documents with an ID and would later do searches for 'similar' documents to one I currently have.

Answer (score 1):

[Whoosh](http://whoosh.ca/) is a pure Python (no C, no external database) indexer / search engine. Check out the [documentation](http://files.whoosh.ca/whoosh/docs/latest/) for more information. It does support stemming.

I tried it out on an XML dump of a mediawiki instance and it seemed to work pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

[Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/). They aren't exactly lightweight but I wouldn't recommend anything smaller, if the project turns out to be successful and it needs to grow, switching the search engine might be painful.

Comment: Can you use Sphinx without a database (MySQL or Postgresql) i.e. feed it directly with files?

Comment: yes, using the xmlpipe2 source: http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#xmlpipe2

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. But are all files xml formatted? My point is that Sphinx is a solution made to index data from a table or XML. It's not a solution for non structured data outside a database.

Comment: Just wrap your documents with the xml needed... it's the same with Solr (except that Solr has Tika for processing binary docs)

Comment: If you have questions about Solr or Sphinx I recommend that you create a real question instead of posting them as comments...

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) is an option. It should allow you to build a custom bag of words search engine.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder about MongoDB http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home

It seems like 'full-text-search' may be what I'm after...
and having additional fields to search with may be handy.